# Referencing Ansible Inventory Hierarchy

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I would like to be able to reference the direct parent of an ansible host as a variable.

Take the following example inventory:

```
[resourcegroup1]
host1
host2

[resourcegroup2]
host3
host4

[application:children]
[resourcegroup1]

[database:children]
[resourcegroup2]

[environoments:children]
[application]
[database]

[enivronoments]
dev
staging
prod
```

I would like to run a looping task in a play which can reference a hosts parent. Example:

```
tasks:
- name: Start Datanbase Servers
  with_items: "{{ groups['database'] }}"   
  azure_rm_virtualmachine:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    resource_group: "{{ item.parent }}"
    started: yes
    allocated: yes
```

{{ item }} would iterate through the values of "host3" and "host4" while I am looking for what I could put in place of {{ item.parent }} that would be the hosts direct parent, in this case: "resourcegroup2".

Is there any way to reference the hierarchy of an inventory?

Comment: Hi @Drew, It's quite possible the functionality you're interested in may not be built into Ansible. What are you trying to accomplish by knowing the hierarchy of an inventory?  Maybe there's another approach to what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some quick research, it appears Ansible doesn't have that sort of functionality builtin.

According to the tickets opened in Ansible Github repo, it sounds like people were interested in this feature, but was never developed. Probably because of the battle between usefulness & complexity.

[Ansible Tix](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/16026)

[Ansible Tix](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/9070+)

Here are some snippets from the above links:

> It would be nice to have a way of recreating inventory group hierarchy inside i.e. Jinja2 template.
>
> @kinvaris We have dynamic inventories for this. You could just write a small dynamic inventory script, and have it translate. I don't see why this is a necessary addition, it only complicates the tools even more.

If you just want a list of groups associated with a host, but don't care about hierarchical structure:

`'{{hostvars["host1"]}}'`

You'll get an list like this:

```
"groups": {
            "all": [
                "host"
            ],
            "child": [
                "host1"
            ],
            "parent": [
                "host1"
            ],
            "ungrouped": []
        },
```

Comment: Thanks for responding Michael

I just gave that a whirl

`ok: [localhost] => (item=host1) => {
 "msg": ""
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=host2) => {
 "msg": ""
}`
 
It seems our ansible tower hasn't cached any facts and the playbook doesn't pull any hostvars (and I currently have none set).

Is there no way to query the inventory (in this case it is an ansible tower inventory) and pull out the children of the "database" group?

Something like:
    {{ inventory.database }}

Comment: "All" group is "at the top" because the dictionary was printed in alphabetical order. But as dictionaries are unsorted, the order in the above transcript is coincidental.

Comment: @techraf You're right! I've done some research and it looks like whatc Drew is asking about isn't a feature in Ansible. Let me update my answer.

Comment: Thanks Michael for the research and response. What @kinvaris stated about dynamic inventory is exactly my goal: To pull in data dynamically from Azure and add a bit of meta data to group resource groups together. After that, I would just like to have tasks run through all servers of the meta group but still be able to reference the resourcegroupname pulled in via dynamic inventory.

However, if it isn't a feature, it isn't a feature.

Thanks again Michael.